# Игра змейка, хранение данных

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, хранение-данных

Начал создавать небольшую игру "Змейка" (есть клеточное поле, по ней ползает змейка, в моей версии на поле до 4х змеек).

Клетка могут быть:

- сводна
- занята
- голова, хвост, тело змеи (для каждой из 4-ех змей)

Наткнулся на вопрос хранения и обработки данных, пока есть пару идей:

**1 вариант**

Хранить всё на поле (в массиве), кодируя к примеру в числами: 0 - свободно, 1 - стенка, 11 - голова змеи1, 12 - тело змеи1, 13 - хвост змеи1, 21 - голова змеи2, и т.д. И при этом хранить небольшие параметры змей в переменных/ массиве: Положение головы (чтобы не искать), направление движения змеи.

**2 вариант**

Создать некий класс, для змеи на поле, который будет хранить положение, направление и все что угодно для змеи.

у каждого варианты я вижу плюсы и минусы, **какой вариант лучше?**, если есть другие предложения, пишите :)

Comment: Расскажите, ради интереса, какие плюсы вы увидели в первом варианте.

Comment: @Котик: вариант №1 позволяет проще отслеживать столкновения, зная куда передвинется змея. Знание того, куда передвинется змея, по-человечески реализуется с вариантом №2. Так что я бы навскидку использовал _оба_ представления, поддерживая консистентность между ними.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать легкость в определении соседних клетках, к примеру знаем что голова змеи1 на координатах (5,5), чтобы определить что происходит в соседних клетках нам нужно всего лишь пройтись по этим клеткам. А во 2ом варианте, необходимо еще проходить по объектам каждой из змей, в поисках, "а не она ли находиться на этой клетке"

Comment: @IVsevolod я за ооп модель, все зависит от реализации модели. Обычно объект сам знает на каких он клетках и сам подскажет о столкновении. мне кажется это лучше чем каждый раз сканировать массив с кучей условий и прочего. в т.ч. и ошибок

Comment: @VladD объединение вариантов достаточно хорошая мысль :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Змея растет с головы, поэтому на карте достаточно проверить только одну клетку карты в каждый момент времени.
Если в данный момент времени змея не растет, значит надо уменьшить хвост.

итого:

- змея - это очередь (fifo), элемент очереди - координаты.
- карта - двумерный массив со змеями, препятствиями и едой.

Comment: в том числе для змеи с AI, которая должна определить куда ей сходить, продолжить движение или поменять направление

Comment: @Yura Ivanov карта - двумерный массив, а если карта без краев? (бесконечная)

Comment: @perfect вместо массива достаточно использовать хэшмэп, где хранятся данные о заполнении чем-либо, "массив" тут в обобщенном смысле...

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ. От списка клеток змеи никуда не деться - надо уметь удалять хвост с поля, когда змея двигается. Двумерное поле тоже лучше сделать - для отрисовки, для проверки столкновений. Будет небольшое дублирование информации, но в смысле скорости всё будет эффективно

Comment: @МихаилМ Массив для змеи создавать не нужно. Достаточно в массиве поля числом закодировать, куда сместилась голова змеи, чтобы потом в хвосте найти следующий квадратик.