# Алгоритм игры "змейка"

Tags: canvas, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, я недавно начал работать с canvas, до этого с графикой не работал. Вот решил попробовать написать всем известную игры змейку, только вот алгоритм никак продумать не могу. Единственное что я понял, что вся змея будет представлена в виде массива, только как поворачивать не всю а начинаю с головы вот это не понятно, прошу помочь)

Comment: Вопрос желательно разделить или обозначить, в чём проблема: нарисовать пиксел на canvas? Или спрайтовую морду змеи с учётом поворота? Или понять, где пикселы рисовать, а где не рисовать?

Comment: @artemryzhov обычно в Гугл отправляют в случае, если ответ на вопрос прост и очевиден, либо вопрос задавался миллион раз. Не спорю, вопрос задан коряво и довльно некомпетентно, но я бы не стал утверждать, что ответ на него очевиден

Comment: Дежавю...
... я тоже пишу игру змейка ) и тоже на canvas...
конкурент?

Comment: Да, Вы правы, возможно ответ не очевиден, но информации по данному вопросу много, и мне показалось что быстрее будет найти ответ в гугле, чем ждать пока здесь на него кто-нибудь ответит, при чем ответ будет содержать ту же информацию, которая уже есть в гугле.
В любом случае, спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может кто не видел [демку с объяснением](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-game-tutorial-make-a-snake-game-using-html5-canvas-jquery).
Внизу страницы можно выбрать скорость воспроизведения и посмотреть как автор пишет её с нуля.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте похожий вопрос: 
[Игра змейка, хранение данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/234470/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: хех, вот и на мои вопросы ссылки появляются )))